# R Caret train / rfe optimize for positive predictive value instead of Accuracy or Kappa

Tags: r, caret, train, cohens-kappa, scoring-rules

In train or rfe I can only set Accuracy or Kappa. Is there a way to edit the functions to define a scoring function? I am using Kappa at the moment but I need to optimize for positive predictive Value (= hit rate = fraction of positives recognized as positive). Of course it is not that simple as 16/20 correct is better than 8/10 correct. So I would say (#hits * ppv)

```
# for 16/20: 16* 0.8 = score of 12.8
# for 8/10: 8* 0.8 = score of 6.4

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,method = "repeatedcv",number = 10,repeats = 4, verbose = TRUE)

lmProfile <- rfe(x = dtrain[,predictors], y = dtrain[,target],
                     newdata = dtest,
                     sizes = c(1:15,20,25),
                     metric="Kappa",
                     ntree = 100,
                     rfeControl = ctrl)
```

Answer (score 5):

A custom summary function and metric can be supplied to caret's `train()` and `trainControl()` to optimize by a metric not included in the default.

Caret includes an alternative summaryFunction, `twoClassSummary()`. However, it doesn't include positive predictive value (aka precision). You can copy and modify `twoClassSummary()` to also include the precision metric, using caret's `posPredValue()` function. In the below example, all I did was append the precision calculation to the `out` object.

```
twoClassSummaryCustom = function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
{
  lvls <- levels(data$obs)
  if (length(lvls) > 2)
    stop(paste("Your outcome has", length(lvls), "levels. The twoClassSummary() function isn't appropriate."))
  if (!all(levels(data[, "pred"]) == lvls)) 
    stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")
  rocAUC <- ModelMetrics::auc(ifelse(data$obs == lev[2], 0, 
                                     1), data[, lvls[1]])
  out <- c(rocAUC,
           sensitivity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], lev[1]),
           specificity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], lev[2]),
           posPredValue(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], lev[1]))
  names(out) <- c("ROC", "Sens", "Spec", "Prec")
  out
}
```

Then, supply this function to `trainControl()` and specify the metric name in `train()`. Note that you'll also have to set `classProbs = TRUE`. See here:

```
trctrl    = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 1, summaryFunction = twoClassSummaryCustom, classProbs = T)
dtree_fit = train(target ~ ., data = dtrain, method = "rpart",
                  metric = "Prec", # Specifying the custom metric here
                  trControl=trctrl,
                  tuneLength = 10)
```

Comment: I like this idea/example a lot but it throws various errors for me. A reproducible example would be extremely helpful.